# Uncaught TypeError: loadOptions is not a function at Async.loadOptions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using React-select V 2.2.x in a project, in one of the components I have 2 select-options which they are dependent on each other
(1st select-option loads options from a remote source and when the user selects one of its options; 2nd select-option gets activated and based on 1st select-option value loads options from a remote source  -> so both of 'em are async ); you can see their image below.
[2 dependant selec-options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqpxC.png)
The problem is that I wanted to pass the 1st select-option value as a parameter for the 2nd select-option 'loadOptions' like this:

```
 <AsyncSelect cacheOptions defaultOptions loadOptions={this.filterProvince}
       id="province" className="form-field-name selector" valueKey="value"
       labelKey="label" value={province} onChange={this.provinceChange} />


<AsyncSelect cacheOptions defaultOptions loadOptions={this.getCity(province)}
     id="city" className="form-field-name selector" valueKey="value"
     labelKey="label" value={cityCode} onChange={this.cityChange} isDisabled={province ? false : true} />
```

And here is 'getCity' function body:

```
 getCity(province) {
    const{binCode,username,code} = this.state;

    if(!province || province === '' || province === null || province === undefined){
      console.log('province:',province);
        return  {options: [] ,complete:true}; //here throws an error
    } 

   //preparing data 

    reportService.getCitiesList(data) //make a request to obtain options
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            if (res.success === false && res.message === 'Token is not valid') {
                userService.Authorization();
                this.getCity();
            }
            let result = JSON.parse(res.body);
            let msg = result.message;
            switch (result.Result) {
                case "false":

                    commonHelper.toaster(msg, 'e');
                    break;
                case "true":
                    //console.log(msg);
                    let cities = JSON.parse(msg);

                    const formatted = cities.map((city) => {
                        return Object.assign({}, {
                            value: city.geography_id,
                            label: city.geography_name
                        });
                    });
                    formatted.push({
                        value: '',
                        label: 'none'
                    });
                    console.log(formatted);
                    return {options: formatted , complete: true}; //also here throws an error if we get to it
                    //this.setState({cityOptions:formatted});

                    break;
            };//end of switch
        });

};//end of getCity function
```

so the problem is that passing a parameter to loadOptions function throws this error "Uncaught TypeError: loadOptions is not a function at Async.loadOptions ", can anyone tell me what option I have rather than passing a parameter or why passing a parameter causes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React-Select `loadOptions` takes a method, but in this block of code you're actually passing the return value as the prop, when the prop requires a function:

```
<AsyncSelect cacheOptions defaultOptions loadOptions={this.getCity(province)}
     id="city" className="form-field-name selector" valueKey="value"
     labelKey="label" value={cityCode} onChange={this.cityChange} isDisabled={province ? false : true} />
```

I get what you're trying to do (related select), it's just in how you're implementing it. If `provinceChange` set province on component state, then `getCity` would do something like:

```
getCity = inputValue => {
  const {province} = this.state;
  // go get my city based on province, and filter by inputValue, if not null
};

// ...
<AsyncSelect loadOptions={this.getCity} />
```